# How do I create an UNSIGNED INT for MySQL in a Rails 5 migration?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

With `activerecord (< 5.0, >= 3.2)` I was able to use the `activerecord-mysql-unsigned` gem to create an UNSIGNED INT in my MySQL database, but there's been no updates to that gem and I can't find any documentation regarding native support for that in Rails 5.

Is there an options hash or something that can be called in the add_column method which allows this to be done?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is an option for unsigned integer, bigint, decimal, and float [in the schema adapter for MySQL](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql/schema_definitions.rb) as of Rails 5.1.x

Something like this in your migration will work in Rails 5.1.4

```
  def up
    create_table :unsigned_columns do |t|

      t.integer "positive", :unsigned => true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this by default. i.e. Like overwriting the `NATIVE_DATABASE_TYPES` in Rails 3 and 4. So that by default new tables are created with a BigInt Unsigned `id` column?

Comment: @JoshuaPinter This is one of those places where I would not recommend overwriting the defaults and instead be explicit about these modifications in your migrations. You could modify a generator to automate a default change. Thus not having to write the migration by hand every time. https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#passing-modifiers

Comment: I really do think that `unsigned` should be the default for primary keys when using MySQL in Rails. I created a GitHub Issue to indicate this preference and it seems that Rafael agrees so I'll be writing a PR to get primary keys to be `unsigned bigint` as the default in Rails 6.2. Feel free to show your support on the issue: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/40967

Comment: I agree unsigned should be the default. Looks like from that GH Issue you already have a feature request to have it changed. The only thing I would add here is that performance regression testing is done. Roughly 4 billion id objects is good enough for most small and medium projects. Moving from 4 byte storage to 8 byte storage may linearly or even exponentially increase column traversal and retrieval times.

Comment: Definitely agree with that. But the default column type is already `bigint`. That was changed in Rails 5.1 (https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/26266). The only change I would be making is using `unsigned` instead of `signed`. That shouldn't have any change in performance, right?

Comment: Ah thank you for referencing that pull. I have a hunch unsigned primary key traversal should be faster than signed, but even so more than likely minuscule at best. Still worth a benchmark in my opinion.

Comment: You might be right. When I get around to that PR, I'll see if I can add some benchmarks for comparison. I love me a good benchmark!

Comment: works with 5.0.7 too

Answer (score 0):

If are using rails > 5.1 and you want to have all your primary keys being generated with `unsigned integer` as default type, all that you have to do is adapt your generator in your `config/application.rb` , adding the following code:

```
config.generators do |g|
      # ... other configurations
      g.orm :active_record, primary_key_type: :unsigned_integer
end
```

With that a call to `rails generate model foo bar:string` will create the `id` as unsigned.